# Python: Help me, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: python

I'm learning how to code and to start i want crate a command that when i write "Dio" for example it writes me "Error 404: dio non esiste" but it says that the code is wrong, what am i doing wrong? here's the code

```
name = int(input("Come ti chiami? "))
if name is "Antonio":
    print("Eh no")
if name is "Dio":
    print("Error 404: Dio non esiste")
if name is "Dio porco":
    print("lol")
```

Comment: Please don't tag C++ if the question has nothing to do with it

Comment: Please be more specific when giving a  title to your question. Every Python question could have that title.

Comment: you are using the wrong title for your question surely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`is` checks if two values **are exactly the same reference**. Since you're inputting one value from a user and the other is hard coded, they won't be the same reference. Instead, you should use the `==` operator. Additionally, if you're inputting a name, you shouldn't convert the input to an `int`:

```py
name = input("Come ti chiami? ")
if name == "Antonio":
    print("Eh no")
if name == "Dio":
    print("Error 404: Dio non esiste")
if name == "Dio porco":
    print("lol")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have taken input of type int:

Instead just take :

```
name = input("Come ti chiami? ")
```

which would be string by default,
and use **"=="** to compare.

But if you have just started learning, I would suggest first go through the python documentation which would give you a basic understanding of how to write python codes.